# Will this PCI NIC work in my desktop?

Tags: networking, motherboard

not sure if this is the right place to ask, and I know it may seem like a bit of a stupid question, but my current desktop has an Asus P8Z77-M motherboard in, and all of my PCIe slots are used up, leaving a PCI slot (seen on [here](https://www.asus.com/media/global/products/7yxGrS52FngihsKT/chwDNC1LJjNvJs6r_500.jpg)).

I am looking to install an additonal 1 gigabit NIC, and I know PCIe isn't an option, and am asking whether something like [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-LINK-TG-3269-Gigabit-Network-Interface/dp/B000FO6QWM) would work in my system (i'm not too worried about drivers, there seems to be a Windows 8 one on the website so I don't see why 8.1 wouldn't be fine).

I'm only asking as I had an old PCI card, and that didn't fit in the socket (not keyed properly), maybe a different revision?

Comment: As is it is a too specific question.  As for not fitting, see wikipedia on 3.3v and 5v keying for PCI devices.  (guessing that is the not-fit part).

Comment: So would it be correct to assume that the example card linked is a Universal (3.3v+5v) card, and that it would work fine in the 5v slot on my board. Also, i'm guessing the 32-bit part is independant of the OS architechture? (running 64-bit windows) Just checking.

Comment: "Supports 32-bit 33/66MHz PCI Bus" so its just a bus requirement which is standard for pci v2.2, you will however need a 64 bit driver for windows.

Comment: @Moab - I see no mention of the user using a 64-bit operating system?

Comment: @deejay31 - Yes; it should work; a proper answer requires you explain what didn't fit though.  Don't read to much into the product title amazon gave this SKU, Amazon's prodcut descriptions, are not always accurate.

Comment: Thanks for your help, only £5 if it doesn't work. @Ramhound, it was assumed correctly that I am running a 64-bit OS, and there appears to be a driver.

Comment: @deejay31 - No problemo.

Comment: I'm clairvoyant today...